# Playing Media player in Android app

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating a media player with start, pause, stop buttons. Start and stop buttons work fine, the problem is with the pause button.

When no audio files are playing (and also not at all paused any audio), if I click on the pause button, it throws this error message:

> Unfortunately App has stopped

What is the problem?

```
public class activity_12 extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer sound;
    int paused;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_12);
    }
    public void Play(View view) {
        if(sound==null) {
            sound=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.fil);
            sound.start();
        }else if(!sound.isPlaying()) {
            sound.seekTo(paused);
            sound.start();
        }
    }
    public void Pause(View view) {
        sound.pause();
        paused=sound.getCurrentPosition();
    }
    public void Stop(View view) {
        sound.release();
        sound=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code@Mohammed Farhan

Comment: Yea wt ever u telling is ryt. But in case if any body miss touch the pause button when no audio is playing then it will show err msg as i said *above*. I just want to stop that err to be displayed on miss touch of pause button.

Comment: And also i used ur code but it shows err msg again. Plzz help me to ovoid it.

Comment: In that case if the user touches the button mistakenly,give a Toast that no audio is playing.By the way if you are still facing the problem please upload your code,so that we can debug it properly.@Mohammed Farhan

Comment: Ok ill upload it in a hour.

Comment: public class activity_12 extends Activity { MediaPlayer sound; int paused; @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_12); } public void Play(View view) { if(sound==null) { sound=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.fil); sound.start(); }else if(!sound.isPlaying()) { sound.seekTo(paused); sound.start(); } } public void Pause(View view) { sound.pause(); paused=sound.getCurrentPosition(); } public void Stop(View view) { sound.release(); sound=null; } }

Comment: Thats my code. Check it whats wrong with that

Comment: No not like this,its not readable @Mohammed,I have edited the code in your question,Please approve the edit and it will be visible in your Question.

Comment: So sorry for inconvince am new to this stack app. Ill aprove it.

Comment: There is an approve option in the upper right corner.Press the button and you are done with it the revised code will be shown in your answer.@Mohammed Farhan.

Comment: @CrazyAndroid. Am not getting that opion button

Comment: Search it properly you will get it.@Mohammed

Comment: Seriously i tried  alot but i coundnt find it.

Comment: Take someone's help or search in google.How to approve someone's question in stackoverflow.?

Comment: @CrazyAndroid, can u see my edited question??

Comment: Yes Now I can see it@Mohammed farhan

Comment: I have edited my answer,Please check it out.@Mohammed Farhan.

Comment: Thank you much u solved my problem. Can i use LinearLayout insted of RelativeLauout???

Comment: Yes,definately you can use LinearLayout.

Comment: @CrazyAndroid, Thank you soo much. 

Comment: But ur code is not making use of raw.audio files. How can i play audio file then.

Comment: Ok i can create mediaplayer for my audio file. Thanks 

Comment: Yes I have just shown you a example.You can use your audio or mp3 files. enjoy coding :)

Comment: I created a button1 after clicking that another layout will open which consists of media player. Ill  play audio file by clicking play button there and if i  exit from that main button ie button1 then audio should stop no matter if its already playing are not. What will be the code for button1??

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the problem because you are not declaring the functions properly.Please check this code:

Define your XML like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >  
  <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button1"  
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"  
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"  
        android:text="start" />  

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button2"  
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"  
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"  
        android:text="pause" />  

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button3"  
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"  
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"  
        android:text="stop" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

You should define your Activity like this:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.os.Environment;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.Button;  

public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
    Button start,pause,stop;  
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        pause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);  
        stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);  
        //creating media player  
        mediaPlayer= new MediaPlayer();



        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                mediaPlayer.start();  
            }  
        });  
        pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                mediaPlayer.pause();  
            }  
        });  
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                mediaPlayer.stop();  
            }  
        });  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, MediaPlayer's states are very particular. If you call a state checking function like `isPlaying()` at the wrong time or in your case `.pause()` at the wrong time, it will automatically transition to an error state. You need to track the state closely yourself.

Check out the MediaPlayer docs, in particular the [State Diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram)

And for pause it says in regard to it's relevant states in calling the `pause()` function:

> Successful invoke of this method in a valid state transfers the object to the Paused state. Calling this method in an invalid state transfers the object to the Error state.

An Error state with MediaPlayer invokes a crash.